# Show a list in a Sonar Widget

Tags: plugins, widget, sonarqube, measure

In my custom Sonar widget, i want to show a property of my pom.xml.
The value of that property is a list of data like this :

```
- In malis noluisse per, mel vidit mutat ex
- Ad propriae argumentum sed, noster minimum splendide
- ea nam. Quot nullam reprimique vis id
- prompta albucius no sea. Nec albucius sensibus ea
```

I create a an erb file and use the function format_measure to show the value :

```
<div class="widget-row">
    <div class="widget-span widget-span-6">
        <div class="widget-measure-container">
            <div class="widget-measure widget-measure-main">
                <span class="widget-label">Label :</span><br/>
                <pre>
                    <%= format_measure('list_value') %>
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

but format_measure add a span tag around the value, here is the rendering :

```
<div class="widget-row">
    <div class="widget-span widget-span-6">
        <div class="widget-measure-container">
            <div class="widget-measure widget-measure-main">
                <span class="widget-label">Label :</span><br/>
                <pre>
                    <span class="nowrap">
                        - In malis noluisse per, mel vidit mutat ex
                        - Ad propriae argumentum sed, noster minimum splendide
                        - ea nam. Quot nullam reprimique vis id
                        - prompta albucius no sea. Nec albucius sensibus ea
                    </span>
                </pre>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Is there another way to show measure value without that span ?
I tried things like : <%= metric('identcard_revue_code').value %> 
but it doesn't work.
Is there good examples somewhere ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution :

```
<%= @snapshot.measure('list_value').formatted_value %>
```

With that api, i could print the value of my measure without span around.
In fact, it's the solution to create your own html structure.